# Decrease row height on click on searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have some tableviewcells loaded on my tableview. Each of those cells has an arrow button at the top right on the click of which the height of the row is increased and some more buttons are exposed. Clicking on the button again hides the button & the height is decreased as before. The code for that is given like so...

```
func moreOptionsBtnTapped(cell: CustomersTableViewCell) {

    if i == 0 {
        if let indexPath = tableView?.indexPath(for: cell) {

            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        }
        i += 1
    } else {
        if let indexPath = tableView?.indexPath(for: cell) {
            selectedIndex = indexPath as NSIndexPath
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        }

        i = 0
    }
}
```

The `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is given as:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath == selectedIndex as IndexPath {
        if i == 0 {
            return 92  
        } else {
            return 66
        }
    }
return 66
```

}

Now the issue is I also have a search bar on top and on click of that searchbar, if the additional buttons are exposed on the tableview cell then I want them to be minimised. Mere hiding them doesn't work. That has been tried.

Hope somebody can help...

Comment: Can you tell where search bar is aded and on tap of search bar you want to minimised exposed button of all cells?

Comment: yes..you are right...

Comment: if I got you right, the search bar is added on the top of tableview below the navigation bar...

Comment: Ok.Variable i you have used as flag for exposed button.If yes, Then how you maintained i for every cell?

Comment: initially `i` is made 0 in `viewDidLoad`. So on the first click i is 0 & when i is zero expose the buttons. And at this point value of i is also incremented so on the next click the buttons are hidden...Hope u got it..

Comment: If i=0 then for every cell buttons are exposed??

Comment: No..only for the particular cells whose down arrow is clicked. The rest will remain as they are...

Comment: So how you tracking which cell buttons to expose and which cells button to minimised as you are using single variable called i for entire table view cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are clicking on search bar you will get the call back on UISearchBarDelegate methods like

```
optional public func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool // return NO to not become first responder
```

in this method you can change the i value and reload the table view. and in this method you are not getting the indexPath for rows , thats why you use this...

```
 self.tableview.relaodData()
```